# Does Sequelize paranoid true affect query performance?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize supports the concept of [paranoid tables](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html).

> A paranoid table is one that, when told to delete a record, it will
> not truly delete it. Instead, a special column called deletedAt will
> have its value set to the timestamp of that deletion request.
>
> Every query performed by Sequelize will automatically ignore soft-deleted records (except raw queries, of course).

Does this slow down `findAll` queries, given the implicit where clause?

Answer (score 2):

It affects like any other similar **WHERE** conditions using a datetime column and `>=` operator. It depends on how many records you have, the column data selectivity, is there an index on the column or do you have any other conditions, joins and so on.

You should build a SQL query plan for a particular query and look at its part that corresponds to the datetime condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm exploring this issue currently but it seems like that it likely *could* incur a non-negligible performance cost out-of-the-box for complex queries. The driving factor would be that deletion is tracked by a *nullable* timestamp and therefore retrieval of non-deleted records require testing for nulls which is less likely to be answerable through index data alone.

For simple queries this may not be noticeable as the DB can quickly filter out those records and may be optimized to do so, but in the case of filtering off of joined data this is likely to require loading a lot of additional data. Partial index support in the DB may help or there may be some tweaks to Sequelize to make use of a zero value or something which can be tested against more easily. Viewing the query plan can hopefully shed light on the details.